# Dynamic if conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, dynamic

Is there anyways to pass the condition for if statement dynamically along with its operator without using eval() or new function() that affects it's performance.

```
<script>

var Students =  [{
            "name": "Raj",
             "Age":"15",
            "RollNumber": "123",
            "Marks": "99",
              
        }, {
            "name": "Aman",
             "Age":"14",
            "RollNumber": "223",
            "Marks": "69",
           },
           {
            "name": "Vivek",
             "Age":"13",
            "RollNumber": "253",
            "Marks": "89",
           }
        ];



*Number of condition are dynamic. can even contain 3 or 4 condition at a time*

var condition = [{"attribute":"el.Age","operator":">=","value":14},
                 {"attribute":"el.Marks","operator":"<=","value":70}];

var newArray =Students.filter(function (el)
{
  if( condition[0].attribute condition[0].operator condition[0].value && condition[1].attribute condition[1].operator condition[1].value ){
  
return true;
  
});

console.log(newArray);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you pass the operands and the operator into a function that dispatches based on the operator to something that does the operation.

As a code sketch:

```
const operators = new Map([
    ["<", lt],
    [">", gt],
    ["<=", lte],
    [">=", gte],
    // ...
]);
function evaluate(operator, leftOperand, rightOperand) {
    const evaluator = operators.get(operator);
    if (!evaluator) {
        throw new Error(`Unknown operator ${operator}`);
    }
    return evaluator(leftOperand, rightOperand);
}
```

...where `lt`, `gt`, etc. are functions that perform the operation. I've used `operator`, `leftOperand`, and `rightOperand` above, but you could use `attribute` and `value` if you prefer. You'll need something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path) to get the value of the "attribute" (the JavaScript term is "property").

(Or you could do the operations in the `evaluate` function itself in a big `switch`.)

Then you use that function in the `filter`:

```
let newArray = Students.filter(student => conditions.every(({operator, attribute, value}) => {
    const leftOperand = getProperty(student, attribute);
    return evaluate(operator, leftOperand, value);
}));
```

I've used `every` there because you're using an `&&` condition. (Note I renamed the `condition` array to `conditions` since arrays hold more than one value.)